# Creating percent of total column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to figure out how to add a % of total column for each state and year in pandas.

my data looks like this

```
year type   Arizona_total Utah_total California_total Colorado_total 
2018 Total    163,176      90,344       343,343          32,343
2018 bio.     272          270            234.            2343
```

The data then continues for each major back until 1990. I want to create a column that is a percent of total majors in that state during that year for each state.

I am a newbie and I apologize for the simple / poorly worded question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
total = np.sum(df.ix[:,'Arizona_total':].values)
df['percent'] = df.ix[:,'Arizona_total':].sum(axis=1)/total * 100
df
```